# Are cream-filled pastries allowed in my carry-on?

Tags: food-and-drink, airport-security, hand-luggage

I want to bring small cream-filled snacks for family and friends.
Is it allowed? Small things like Twinkies, mini-cupcakes and so on in the one allowed carry-on. Or will airport security confiscate them?

Comment: This depends. Where are you travelling from, and to, and which airline are you flying with?

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for responding. I'll be flying within the united states from DFW using US Airways

Answer (score 5):

For traveling from or within the United States, foods that are in and of themselves in the form of a liquid or gel are not permitted, but those which may simply contain liquids or gels are permitted. Unfortunately **[your mileage may vary](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/practical-travel-safety-issues/1229163-bring-food-through-security.html)** depending on the interpretation of the screeners. You will find some, mostly older, anecdotes of jelly doughnuts or chocolate liqueur truffles being blocked, so having the food items checked or shipped, or purchased airside of the screening, would be safer options.

[The TSA advises](http://www.tsa.gov/traveler-information/traveling-food-or-gifts) (note: not a comprehensive list):

> Here's a list of liquid, aerosol and gel items that you should put in your checked bag, ship ahead, or leave at home if they are above the permitted 3.4 oz.
>
> - Cranberry sauce
> - Cologne
> - Creamy dips and spreads (cheeses, peanut butter, etc.)
> - Gift baskets with food items (salsa, jams and salad dressings)
> - Gravy
> - Jams
> - Jellies
> - Lotions
> - Maple syrup
> - Oils and vinegars
> - Perfume
> - Salad dressing
> - Salsa
> - Sauces
> - Snow globes
> - Soups
> - Wine, liquor and beer
>
> You can bring **pies and cakes** through the security checkpoint, but please be advised that they are subject to additional screening.

I don't know what kind of "additional screening" one can do on a cake, or how ten ounces of filling inside a pie crust is somehow less deadly than six ounces of soft cheese in wax paper, but that's the government for you.